# NDK compiling error caused by __Atomic, when using RefBase or IBinder

Tags: android, c++, c++11, makefile, android-ndk

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to make a NDK project and using IBinder and RefBase(looper, sp, wp certainly necessary).
But even before linking, an compiling error happens:

> arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/include/stdatomic.h:40:9: error: '_Atomic' does not name a type
> typedef _Atomic _Bool atomic_bool;

then every symbol in stdatomic.h cannot be recognized.

I have using some C++11 flag as below, and tried some random CFLAGS:

> -D_GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T -DUSE_CPUSETS
>
> -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -pthread -frtti -fexceptions

Im noticed that the stlport file stdatomic.h didn't include other header files, so I guess there should be one or more Compile macros.

But I am new to NDK build, wish some one could give me some suggestions to this problem.

many thanks@!!@

Comment: You probably **`#include`** headers for **libbinder** and for **libutils**, which are not part of the NDK. This requires extra care. How are your headers organized?

Comment: I'll check it and send you feedbacks, sorry for late response.

Comment: @Josefus.mv Any update for this Question, as i am also facing same issue.. can you please post Answer.

Comment: @AlexCohn if i am using libbinder & libutils then what care i need to take?

Comment: @Explore: in the nutshell, you don't need STL to work with system libraries, e.g. libbinder. The compilation errors above have nothing to do with dependencies on RefBase *et al*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you fix this?

I had this problem too and finally solved it by updating the `NDK` to `android-ndk-r12b` and set `APP_PLATFORM := android-23` in the `Application.mk` file.